# mod_rewrite rules for existing files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am defining mod_rewrite rule that will rewrite all requests to my /application.php if requested file not exists, and won't do any rewriting otherwise. It is simple:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule .* application.php [PT]
```

There is only one problem with the code. Assume I have foo.html file. Then requests like:

http://example.com/foo.html/some/other/string

will fall with 404 error.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

> will fall with 404 error. Why?

Because that URL doesn't exist. It's looking for the file `string` in the folder `/foo.html/some/other` and it's not there.

The behaviour that you want to exploit using the  `http://example.com/foo.html/some/other/string` URL structure - treating the first entry as a file name, and the rest as a parameter to it - is called ["pathinfo"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo). It has nothing to do with mod_rewrite, but will be available if you enable the following in your Apache configuration:

```
 AcceptPathInfo On
```

it looks like that setting is currently turned to "off" for you.

If you enable it, the part after the file name will be available to `foo.html` - in PHP, it would be in the

```
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]
```

variable.

Because this method doesn't require the rewrite module to be active, this is sometimes called "the poor man's mod_rewrite" - it works fine, but isn't quite as pretty as flexible as "real" rewriting.